# SQL count one field two times in select with different parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I like to have my query count one column two times in my select based on the value. So for example.

**input: table**

```
    id           | type
    -------------|-------------
    1            | 1
    2            | 1
    3            | 2
    4            | 2
    5            | 2
```

**output: query (in 1 row, not two):**
countfirst = 2 (two times 1)
countsecond = 3 (three times 2)

An default count in an select counts all rows in the query. But i like to count rows based
on an number without limiting the query. When using for example WHERE type = '1', type 2
gets filtered and cannot be counted anymore.

Is there an solution for this case in SQL?

--- EXAMPLE USE (situation above is simplefied but case is the same) ---

With one query i get all cars grouped by type from an table. There are two type signs: yellow (in db 1) and grey (in db 2). So in that query i have the folowing output:

Renault - ten times found - two yellow signs - eight grey signs

Comment: Please mention what the input is and the expected output. Your description is bit confusing.

Comment: I changed some things in my question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: u just wanna count the `type` column rite?? as 1 is twice and 2 is thrice

Comment: I post an example in my question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a table, script is given below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temptbl](
[id] [int] NULL,
[type] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Execute the insert script as

```
insert into [temptbl] values(1,1)
insert into [temptbl] values(2,1)
insert into [temptbl] values(3,2)
insert into [temptbl] values(4,2)
insert into [temptbl] values(5,2)
```

Then execute the query.

```
;WITH cte as(
  SELECT [type], Count([type]) cnt 
  FROM temptbl 
  GROUP BY [type]
)
SELECT * FROM cte
pivot (Sum([cnt]) for [type] in ([1],[2])) as AvgIncomePerDay
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This solution could work but we use large queries and with this solution we need to copy the whole query two times..

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This looks like the right solution. There is an small problem with the result. 1 and 2 gives an number or an null. So when 1 gives an number, 2 gives an null and vice versa... Did i do something wrong?

Comment: I got your point.
I modified the answer, please follow the steps.

Comment: You can use alias for [type] if type's are not unlimited for example
case when [type] = 1 then 'firstcol' when [type] = 2 then 'secondcol' end as [type]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I unfortunately cant create or change data on the SQL server so testing is a little bit difficult. I have an MYSQL db to test, but i think this query does not run on an MYSQL or am i mistaking..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GROUP BY` clause as Mureinik suggested, but with the addition of a `WHERE` clause to filter the results.

Below shows the results for type = 1 (assuming `type` is an `INT`:

```
 SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS NoOfRecords
   FROM table
  WHERE type IN (1)
  GROUP BY type
```

So if we wanted 1 and 2 we can use:

```
 SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS NoOfRecords
   FROM table
  WHERE type IN (1, 2)
  GROUP BY type
```

Lastly, that `IN` statement can pull `type` from another query:

```
 SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS NoOfRecords
   FROM table
  WHERE type IN (SELECT type FROM someOtherTable)
  GROUP BY type
```